# How to get division to produce float value in c++

Tags: c++

I was looking back into a calculator I made a while back and noticed that the division did not work, calculating expressions such as 3/4 as 0. I tried to fix it by converting from ints to floats, something which I did not know at the time of making the calculator. For some reason, however, it does not work. Am I messing up the syntax?

Code:

```
int divide(int num1, int num2) {
    float quot;
    quot = (float) num1 / num2;
    return quot;
}
```

Whenever I call my divide function, it gives me integer answers. I want fractional (decimal) answers.

Comment: Change the return type of the function to `float`.   Returning an `int` specifies that an integer will be returned.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was dumb, just figured it out. I needed to define my division function as `float divide`.

```
float divide(int num1, int num2) {
    float quot;
    quot = (float) num1 / num2;
    return quot;
}
```

Comment: Just a point about terminology: you need to change the **return type** of the function from `int` to `float`. A function has a **name**, an **argument list**, and a **return type**. In the code above, the name of the function is `divide`; its argument list is `int num1, int num2`; and its return type is `floats.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the int to float in your function return type